# Google stack Chart not rendered when data is assigned from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, charts, google-visualization

I need to develop a stacked chart in Google Charts and I'm new to it.
Here is the sample code for generating the chart.

```
function drawChart()
    {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(["Label", "I", { role: "style" }, "J", { role: "style" }, "K", { role: "style" }, "M", { role: "style" }],["MJ1", 0.05, "#808080", 0.0775, "#C71585", 0.069, "#FFC0CB", 0.05, "Blue"],["MJ2", 0.05, "Yellow", 0.0775, "Pink", 0.069, "#808080", 0.05, "black"]);
       var options = {
            width: 1000,
            height: 550,
            legend: { position: 'none', maxLines: 6, textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 10 } },
            isStacked: true,                
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

The above mentioned code is working fine. But when I change the data to a variable and use that variable as mentioned below, the graph is not generated.

```
var temp = '["Machine", "I", { role: "style" }, "J", { role: "style" }, "K", { role: "style" }, "M", { role: "style" }],["MJ1", 0.05, "#808080", 0.0775, "#C71585", 0.069, "#FFC0CB", 0.05, "Blue"],["MJ2", 0.05, "Yellow", 0.0775, "Pink", 0.069, "#808080", 0.05, "black"]';

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([temp]);
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.
Reason : I have written a WCF service which returns the simple string in the same format as temp variable string data.
Thanks in advance!
JSFiddle for the same - http://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/79ffvayr/653/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transform your string into a correct JSON string, so:

- embed your `temp` string into array delimiters *[]*:

  `var temp = '['+temp+']';`
- enclose property names in double quotes:

  `temp = temp.replaceAll('role', '"role"');`
- at last JSON parse the string and pass the result to `arrayToDataTable()` method:

  `var json = JSON.parse(temp);
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(json);`

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/zh7upjoz/